# how to capture the HTTPResponseBody data in ASP.Net?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous, ihttpmodule

I have written a HTTPModule after deriving from **IHttpModule** as follows.

```
public void Init(HttpApplication httpApplication)
{
    EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper taskAsyncHelper = new EventHandlerTaskAsyncHelper(LogMessage);
    httpApplication.AddOnBeginRequestAsync(taskAsyncHelper.BeginEventHandler, taskAsyncHelper.EndEventHandler);
}

private async Task LogMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
           var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
            var ctx = app.Context;
           string myURL = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Request.Url.ToString();

          StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Request.InputStream);

            try
            {
                string body = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;
            }

            StreamReader ResponseStreamReader = new StreamReader(((HttpApplication)sender).Context.Response.OutputStream);

}
```

The StreamReader code is throwing error(the exact error message is: System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable).

How can I read the ResponseBody of a HTTP request.
I am using .Net 4.5.
Thank you,
John

Comment: Since this is BeginRequest, won't the response body be empty because nothing has happened yet?

Comment: Are you by chance trying to log the REQUEST, not the RESPONSE? As Paul mentioned, there is no response at this point in the lifecycle, thus nothing to log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OutputStream represents the output as it is being written, so you may need to set the reader position to 0 before attempting to read from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it that way. The OutputStream is a write-only-stream.

Another approach is to use the Filter-property on the response object, see

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/post-processing-the-output-of-aspnet-pag/212001499

I am using the following code:

```
public class LogModule : IHttpModule
{
    private string _filename;

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
        _filename = "C:\\Temp\\iislog.log";
        app.PostRequestHandlerExecute += OnPostRequestHandlerExecute;
    }

    private void OnPostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        if (app != null)
        {
            app.Response.Filter = new FilterStream(app.Response.Filter, _filename);
        }
    }
}

internal class FilterStream : MemoryStream
{
    private readonly Stream _outputStream;
    private readonly string _fileName;

    public FilterStream(Stream outputStream, string filename)
    {
        _outputStream = outputStream;
        _fileName = filename;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(_fileName, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
        _outputStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```